# if-else block not working properly in android

Tags: android, if-statement

Scenario: when the focus is lost from an EditText, I'm checking if it contains null (in the first if block).
If so, then I'll show a Toast.
In the else-if block I'm checking if the EditText doesn't contain letters.
Then I'll show a toast, but when I run the application, the Toast is shown even on a correct input.
I.e.: If I enter any letter the Toast should not be shown, it should be shown only when a null or digit/special symbol is entered.

Here is the code

```
et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                a = et1.getText().toString();
                if (a.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your entry is incorrect!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if (!a.contains("[a-z]")||!a.contains("[A-Z]")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your entry is incorrect!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                }
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i don't understand, didn't you read the documentation for `contains`, first?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because:

```
if (a == "")
```

won't work in Java

Use

```
if (a.equals(""))
```

instead

---

Also, `String.contains` doesn't use regular expressions, but CharacterSequences.
So, unless your string doesn't contain the exact character sequences `"[a-z]"` or `"[A-Z]"` (and only one of these 2 strings), you'll never get a match.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Just to add clarity: for objects (a == "") compares the references, in memory, between a and "". Using the String.equals(a,b) method compares the values of the strings.

Comment: @lacraig2 Thank you for the enrichment.

Comment: In Android we have also _TextUtils.isEmpty(String)_ which compares against _null_ and empty string.

Comment: that's actually not the problem

Comment: This answer is becoming richer and richer, thank to your comments!

Comment: thanks for th answer,,,but problem is not solved completely,  still if im entering letter it is showing me toast,,, why?

Comment: Because `String.contains` doesn't work on regexes, but on CharacterSequences. So, unless your string doesn't contain the exact sequances "[a-z]" or "[A-Z]" (and only one of these 2 strings), you'll never get a match. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: ohhkkk,,,,, so how to compare??

Comment: This makes for a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The '==' operator only compares references. To compare string values you must use the equals() method.

Instead of

```
if (a == "")
```

use

```
if (a.equals(""))
```

See: [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
if (a == "")
```

Strings can't be compared like this.  Instead, check for size equal to 0, or against a specific string with the `equals()` method.